# Easy way to arrange UIButtons in IB using Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, swift3

I know in life there is no easy way, but I thought I'd ask.

I got 10 UIButtons arranged in a specific arrangement (like a tree with brunches kinda thing).

I would like those buttons to get smaller/bigger when app is launching in different screen sizes (i.e iPhone 5s or 6 or 6+ etc).

Is it possible to set the auto layout in such way that the buttons stay in the same arrangement but become smaller/bigger in IB?

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is **similar** to what I'm trying to achieve.... My drawing is **not** symmetrical.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a great problem for a `UIStackView`.

Give the buttons constraints for aspect ratio (relative to the button), and then CTRL+drag from the buttons to the superview and select `Equal Widths` OR `Equal Heights`.

Then, you can select all of the buttons, and go to Editor(Top of screen) -> Embed in -> Stack View. Set the Stack View's `Distribution` to `Fill Equally`, and give the Stack View constraints relative to the superview.

Comment: I m not sure I am following your example correctly but it doesn't seem to be working... These buttons have specific arrangement like a tree.... they are not one below the other.

Comment: Ah I see. Instead, you could position each button by centering their x and y axis to the super view, and then offsetting (adjusting the multiplier) the center until they are where you want, then do the same restraints for height/width and aspect ratio.

Comment: You would also have to add more restraints to ensure the buttons don't overlap. What you're looking for is pretty complicated. If you can't figure it out I can try to post an example solution tomorrow

Comment: Please see edited question with image. It's not exactly what I'm trying to achieve as this is symmetrical while my drawing is not!